# how to change background color of the ion card systematically

Tags: ionic3

> hi, 
>   i've this ion-card i want to change his background systematically for example detail of card 1 he will take the color red detail of card 2 he will take the color green  until ...N
>   how to do this please and thanks in advance

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let t of allpro">
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      {{t.name}}
    </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.ts` need to include following function

```
  getRandomColor()
  {
      var color = "#";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          var part = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
          color += (part.length > 1) ? part : "0" + part;
      }
      return color;
  }
```

And need to change in `.html`

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let t of allpro">
  <ion-card-content [ngStyle]="{'bacground':getRandomColor()}">
    <ion-card-title>
      {{t.name}}
    </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```